# Is it possible to boot a Wubi/Ubuntu system in a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, wubi

I think the title says it all. Is there any method for doing this? I've Googled around but only found solutions to similar, but not identical problems, and just plain non-answers from people who don't understand why anyone could possibly want to run Windows and Linux in parallell...

I can't see why it shouldn't be possible. Since the entire OS is contained within a disk image, you should be able to simply mount the image as a device in Windows (using D-Tools or the like) and then add it to a virtual machine. I have a feeling, though, that this might be a case of "one does not simply walk into Mordor", which is why I am asking :-)

Comment: I don't recommend Wubi. Clean install is way better and you'll save yourself some headaches.

Comment: Agreed. I mostly used Wubi to do a quick try of Ubuntu. Would it be easier to load the OS in a VM if I did a clean install, though?

Comment: Definitely. But if you're going to do a clean install, do it through the VM so you don't need to install a new bootloader neither will GRUB bother you at system boot.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. Seems like a good question to me, and I'm disappointed there isn't more positive response. Also, the downsides I've seen of Wubi seem minor to me.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly with some craveats - your wubi install is being chainloaded by ntldr, with the actual bootloader (iirc grub, as a file called gldr) - so you would probably boot off some flavour of grub that can load the image - which would require getting grub onto the VM somehow.

Comment: Hmm, well getting grub onto the VM shouldn't be much different from a normal case. Do you think it would be possible to configure grub to access the NTFS partition, mount the image file and boot from it?

Comment: well, i believe so, or mount the image directly, and have a small partition or something for grub

Answer (score 0):

You can run Ubuntu in a virtual machine on Windows via something like Virtualbox: https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Please read my question. I specifically asked if I could run a WUBI-installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Pardon me for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as discussed here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9221317#post9221317

However, the files that person offered are on a now-defunct file-sharing service.